# how to make two lists horizontally central

Tags: html, css, list, alignment, centralized

I have two  lists that I want both to be side by side each other. But also I want them to be central of the page.  They both are within a pure-menu div, so when i try to put an outer div on both  then they seem to hide away / disappear.

example code:

```
<div id="submenu" class="pure-hidden-tablet pure-hidden-desktop pull-left">
    <div class="pure-menu pure-menu-open ">
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
 <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.rightMenu{
   margin-left:20%;
   float:left;
 }
 .leftMenu{
  float:left;
   margin-left:20%;
 }
```

this aligns them together together on one line with the float:left. However I'm struggling to centralise them on a 100% width page.

Comment: You mean like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/w5q6njsu/)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.mem
{
    float:left;
    position: relative;

}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="mem">
<ul>
    <li>hi</li>
    <li>hello</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="mem">
    <ul>
    <li>hi</li>
    <li>hello</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Enclose both the lists in div tags and again put them in a single div and apply css.
Try this it will solve your problem. Don't forget to tick it right.

Answer (score 0):

To center content use a wrapper.

```
.wrapper {
  width: 80%; // define it's width
  margin: 0 auto; // set margins. auto will center it
}
```

Then wrap your markup.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lnsu6xqy/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and easy method using inline block, text-align center and a wrapping div.

```css
.menu-wrap {
  text-align:center;
    }

.menu-wrap ul {
  display:inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="menu-wrap">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
 <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: I tried this method, however a wrapper seems to make the list disappear, maybe something to do with pure-menu's ?

Comment: Probably, what does `pull-left` do in Pure CSS? That's probably related.